# Avoiding duplicate data while exporting?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, automation

I write a Python program to get data from SQL Server for automation. it runs for every n period of time. The problem is whenever it runs, it fetches all the data from table. But all I want to fetch latest records which is inserted into database after previous run of python script.

For example: there are 10 records in the database, the python scripts runs and fetch's all 10 records. Then 5 more records are added to the database and in the 2nd run of Python script it should fetch only those 5 records?

One more condition is without modifying adding columns to that table.

Comment: Does your table already have a `rowversion` (aka `timestamp`) column? If not, does it have any kind of user-defined modified datetime column? Can you enable change tracking or change data capture? Do you only care about inserts, or do you also care about updates? Do you already have any kind of incrementing column, like an `identity`, or a `uniqueidentifier` with a default value of `newsequentialid`? This will be easier to answer if you script out the definition of your table (`create table ...`) and add it to your question.

Comment: You need to provide your table definition in order for anyone to assist.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve what you are describing, if your table has an Identity field, is to have a separate table that holds the latest Id you retrieved data from during the data extraction process.

You would then simply alter the procedure you use to extract data so that it only picks up rows that are after the latest Id held in this separate table, and update it with the maximum Id of the data you have just extracted.

This isn't the cleanest approach by any stretch, but it does achieve what you are asking whilst keeping with the condition of not altering your existing table.